# Prevent page reload in safari due to excessive power usage

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

How can I prevent Safari from refreshing the page showing the message "This web page has been reloaded because it was using significant energy"?

I would like to leave the coinhive miner running when my machine is idle but it always gets stopped by the Safari refreshes.

Thanks

Comment: did you try FF or Chrome

Comment: Yes, with Chrome I achieve a much lower H/s rate and the CPU temperature gets way higher. I'm gonna try with FF.

Comment: FF has the same H/s rate as Chrome (so lower than Safari). Cores temperature is OK though.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this apple support discussion on the matter:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8111881)

> Well, my "solution" so far has been to run that process in Chrome
>   instead of Safari. Not only does Chrome let it run for as long as I
>   like, it turns out that it's able to execute it more than twice as
>   fast (for this particular case).

Comment: Thanks. According to my benchmarks though Safari is faster and warms up the cores way less.